# sequelize belongsToMany where filter

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, hapi

Let's say I have the following models:

```
const Item = sequelize.define("Item", {
    active: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: true },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    description: { type: DataTypes.TEXT } 
  });


const Partner = sequelize.define("Partner", {
    active: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: true },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  });
```

I associate them the following way:

```
models.Item.belongsToMany(models.Partner, {
      as: "vendors",
      through: "PartnerDefaultItems"
    });

models.Partner.belongsToMany(models.Item, {
      as: "items",
      through: "PartnerDefaultItem"
    });
```

I guess my models and associations are okay because it will create a new table in the database with item and partner ids.

Now! I'm doing server side pagination with filtering, and when I select a partner (or more) I only want to return those items associated with the selected partner(s).

Can I do it with only one query?

For example: my frontend sends a request with partnerId: 1...

```
const res = await db.models.Item.findAll({
          where: {select every item with associated partnerId}
        });
```

//-associated table example-//

partner_id: 1  item_id: 1 => partner.partnerId equals with partner_id so select item where item.id = item_id

partner_id: 2  item_id: 2 => partner.partnerId not equals, don't select

etc...

The point is to use single query for this, without any raw sql.

Answer (score 0):

Your query structure should `include` the related table and specify the `through` relationship as well as the `where` for your `partnerId`. You can enable `logging: true` to show the SQL query in the console for further debugging.

```js
const res = await db.models.Item.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: db.models.Parter,
      as: 'partners',
      through: 'PartnerDefaultItem',
      where: {
        id: partnerId,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: I think I'm getting the hang of it. At least it does something. If I do it like you said it gives an error though "Item.vatKeyId" is not defined, but it really is in my database, it's just another simple belongsTo association...     models.Item.belongsTo(models.VatKey);